# RadWindow close on Navigated page

Tags: c#, telerik, radwindow

I open a radwindow on my drop down selectedindex changed and navigate the window to a diff page.

```
 <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="RadWindow1"  NavigateUrl="Default1.aspx"  Width="500px"></telerik:RadWindow>
```

Can some one suggest..how can i close the RadWindow1 in  Default1 "Close" button click.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code inside `Default1` which is loaded inside `RadWindow1`.

It basically calls `RadWindow's close` function when a button is clicked.

### Inside Default1

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function getRadWindow() {
      var oWindow = null;
      if (window.radWindow) 
         oWindow = window.radWindow;
      else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) 
         oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
      return oWindow;
   }

   function onClientClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
      getRadWindow().close();
   }

</script>

<telerik:RadButton ID="CloseRadButton" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
   Text="Close" OnClientClicked="onClientClicked">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/window.aspx) has a close button on it.  This button should just work to close the window.

Take a look at the demos around opening and closing the RadWindow on the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) support page:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/radopen/defaultcs.aspx